# Split long relation over two line using boolean operator

Tags: logic, notation

Normally, when you have a long equation, you can split it on two lines. Suppose that $a$ and $b$ are very long expression. Then, for example:

$$ x = a - b$$

can be rewritten as

$$ x = a + $$ $$\quad-(b)$$

I use $+$ and $-$ to maintain a consistency. What do I have to do when using boolean operator?
For example, I have to split into two lines the followings:

$$x = a \wedge b$$
$$x = a \vee b$$

Which is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to express conjunction $\land$ in terms of disjunction $\lor$, then you'll need to use the negation symbol $\lnot$ so you can use DeMorgan's:  $$x = a\land b \iff x =\lnot(\lnot a \lor \lnot b)$$

Likewise, $$x = a \lor b \iff x = \lnot(\lnot a \land \lnot b)$$

---

If you're simply wanting to split lengthy propositions $a, b$ onto separate lines (for example when trying to format a paper which allows only at most a set number of characters per line, so that you cannot fit all of, say, $a \lor b$ on one line), then you can do either of the following:  $$\begin{align} x &= (a) \lor \\ &\quad (b)\end{align}$$ or else $$\begin{align} x & = (a) \\&\quad \lor  (b)\end{align}$$

Likewise for $x = a \land b$.

I put $a, b$ in parentheses to emphasize that the main connective is $\lor$, (or $\land$, repsectively): that we are connecting *all of $a$* with *all of $b$*.

Comment: the second part of your answer is what I was looking for! Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome. I added the second part because after rereading your question, it occurred to me that *that* might be what you were after!